# scrapy shell doesn't use ipython

Tags: python-3.x, shell, scrapy, ipython

As you can see in the screenshot, ipython is installed and works. Following the offical docs I told the cfg file to use it. But, if it seems that scrapy shell doesn't use it. Is it normal, did I make a mistake.

Why `shell = ipython` doesn't do anything?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I suspect that `scrapy` doesn't use IPython because it doesn't read `scrapy.cfg`. That's project configuration file and you are trying to run `scrapy` from `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. Try the [second way](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) of specifying shell, i.e. set env variable `SCRAPY_PYTHON_SHELL`.

Comment: @TomášLinhart thanks but in which envir. variable should I set SCRAPY_PYTHON_SHELL  : PATH or PYTHONPATH? Your answer also suggest there is another way to use scrapy shell than using the cmd consol. I'm using np++ to run my python, is it possible to run the scrapy shell from there?

Comment: `SCRAPY_PYTHON_SHELL` is the name of the environment variable, you should set its value to `ipython`.

Comment: @TomášLinhart ah! I set the `SCRAPY_PYTHON_SHELL`  envir var to `ipython`. But it doesn't change anything (cf printscreen above).

Comment: @@TomášLinhar I dont really understand how that works, but but I solved it: Scrapy was instaled in conda (virtual envir). Ipython was installed in the normal python. So I also installed ipython on anaconda (using pip on its shell). Now I have 2 ipthon installed, I don't understand why I need both, but it works. You can use that in an answer I'll accept it (I'll delete that comment)

Comment: You solved it, so you can accept your own answer once you post it ;-) The issue you describe didn't come to my mind, but it's logical. When you look [at the code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/c01c1ef2ae5ae923d3a0aa6abdda3065238a3a4a/scrapy/utils/console.py) you'll see that Scrapy doesn't use IPython as a command, but rather its Python package. So they both have to be installed in the same Python environment.

Answer (score 3):

Scrapy shell did not find ipython is because scrapy was instaled in conda (virtual envir.) but Ipython was installed in the normal python (using pip in windows shell).

So I also installed ipython on anaconda (using pip on its shell). Now I have 2 ipthon installed.

The ipython installed in the python folder enable me to get the ipthon shell in the cmd windows. 
The ipython installed in conda allows me to be used by scrapy shell.

As @Tomáš Linhart said, the issue is logical, "When you look at [the code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/c01c1ef2ae5ae923d3a0aa6abdda3065238a3a4a/scrapy/utils/console.py) you'll see that Scrapy doesn't use IPython as a command, but rather its Python package".